# sympy solve() and complex rational numbers

Tags: sympy, complex-numbers, rational-number

The following code:

```
from sympy import *

a, b = symbols("a b")
eqs = [ a + b - 3j, a - b - 2 ]
print(solve(eqs, [a, b]))
```

prints:

```
{a: 1.0 + 1.5*I, b: -1.0 + 1.5*I}
```

I'd like the results to be returned as complex rational numbers not floating point numbers, e.g.:

```
{a: 1 + 3/2*I, b: -1 + 3/2*I }
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a + 3j` becomse `a + 3.0*I` when parsed by SymPy; to keep it Rational, use SymPy's `I`:

```py
>>> from sympy import I
>>> eqs = [ a + b - 3*I, a - b - 2 ]
>>> solve(eqs, [a, b])
{a: 1 + 3*I/2, b: -1 + 3*I/2}
```